# Dell SonicWALL - TZ series Dual Wan

Tags: wan, failover, dell

Can you use dual-WAN with Active/Passive failover on any of the TZ SonicWALL models?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The TZ series can be used for a dual wan connection.

[Configuring WAN Failover & Load-Balancing in SonicOS Enhanced (5.5 and below) (SW7588)](https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw7588):

> **Feature:**
>
> WAN Failover and Load Balancing allows you to designate the one of the
>   user-assigned interfaces as a Secondary or backup WAN port. The
>   secondary WAN port can be used in a simple active/passive setup, where
>   traffic is only routed through the secondary WAN port if the primary
>   WAN port is down and/or unavailable.

For Active/Passive, as described by the article, it is possible to do so.

Edit: on the right section, you see on what appliance it is available (Which includes the TZ series)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually yes, but turns out my question was slightly off. Its actually the case for two Wan Feeds coming into two separate modems and then switches, so its the ability to configure a Redundant interface?

Comment: Just so I understand, you have two separate links, coming into a switch, then there is one cable connecting that switch to the SonicWALL and you would like to have that interface redundant so if one WAN link fall, the other one will take over?

Comment: Close, its two Wan feeds into two switches and then the Firewalls feed off that (one cable per Switch).  both running VRRP so the feed fails over if required.  - I believe I found the answer but welcome comments  - http://documents.software.dell.com/sonicos/6.2/administration-guide/configuring-link-aggregation-and-port-redundancy?ParentProduct=732